# Exposing a callback interface from C++ to Python and passing it back to C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I develop a wrapper of our C++ library for Python users and I have a memory leak when I try to expose a callback interface.

My library code looks like this:

```cpp
// Simulate our library
namespace library {
    // Callback pure interface
    class Callback{
    public:
        virtual ~Callback() {
            // Just for test!
            std::cout << "~Callback() destructed!" << std::endl;
        } 
        virtual void onProgress(int progress) = 0;
    };

    // Some library class who gets and stores callback instance
    class Library {
        std::shared_ptr<Callback> callback;
    public:
        Library(std::shared_ptr<Callback> _callback)
        : callback { _callback } {
            std::cout << "Library() constructed!" << std::endl;
        }

        ~Library() {
            // Ligrary is free!
            std::cout << "~Library() destructed!" << std::endl;
        }

        void func() {
            // Use callback
            if (callback != nullptr) {
                callback->onProgress(66);
            }
        }
    };

    // Show module is unloaded.
    struct Lifecycle {
        ~Lifecycle() {
            std::cout << "Lifecycle has terminated." << std::endl;
        }
    };

    Lifecycle lc;
}
```

Lookup to object `LifeCycle`. It shows message when our module is unloaded.

Next I have a C++ module with `boost::python`

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace py = boost::python;

namespace {
    // Python wrapper for callback
    struct CallbackWrapper
        : library::Callback
        , py::wrapper<library::Callback>
        {
            virtual void onProgress(int progress) override {
                this->get_override("onProgress")(progress);
            }
        };

    // Special testing callback
    struct CallbackWrapperTest
        : library::Callback
        , py::wrapper<library::Callback>
        {
            virtual void onProgress(int progress) override {
                std::cout << "TEST: onProgress(" << progress << ")" << std::endl;
            }
        };

    // Creation finctuon
    std::shared_ptr<library::Library> createLibrary(std::shared_ptr<library::Callback> callback) {
        return std::make_shared<library::Library>(callback);
    }
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(callback) {
    py::class_<library::Library, boost::noncopyable>(
        "Library",
        py::no_init
        )
        .def("__init__", py::make_constructor(&createLibrary))
        .def("func", &library::Library::func)
        ;
    
    py::class_<CallbackWrapper, boost::noncopyable>("Callback");

    py::class_<CallbackWrapperTest, boost::noncopyable>("CallbackTest");
}
```

Class `CallbackWrapperTest` will show the problem late.

My Python code is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"./build")
import callback

class PyCallback(callback.Callback):
    '''Python callback implementation'''
    def onProgress(self, progress):
        print("PY onProgress", progress)

cb = PyCallback()

# Replacing by this works fine but useless
# cb = callback.CallbackTest()

lib = callback.Library(cb)

lib.func()

# explicit library deletion works fine  
# del lib
print("==========================")
```

Note the script doesn't have function "main". It is important.

I have an output:

```
Library() constructed!
PY onProgress 66
==========================
Lifecycle has terminated.
```

There are not messages from destructors! I expect to see

```
~Library() destructed!
~Callback() destructed!
```

I realised some strange thinks:

1. If I wrap script code to a function (e.g. `main()`) dectructors are called.
2. If I add explicit deletion `del lib` desctuctors are called.
3. If I remove Python inheritance and I replace Python class to pure C++ `CallbackTest` desctuctors are called.

But only if I do Python derived class I have a memory leak. I suppose the problem in reference counting, but I don't understand where. Can anybody help me?

[The test project is placed on GitHub](https://github.com/maydyk/cpp_python_callback)

Comment: I didn't understand in detail whether this applies but I've some experiences with CPython in general. We're using Python as a kind of macro language to be used in our GUI. Originally, we tried to init a Python interpreter for every individual Python script call to prevent unintended "communication" between independent script calls. With this approach we ended up with a similar memory leak issue which was that significant that we started to investigate. This ended up somehow hopeless. Finally, we decided to init the Python interpreter once at appl. startup and re-use it for every script.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we were, of course, aware of the need for the corresponding Python interpreter shut-down for every init. That was the first thing we checked in our code... ;-) CPython is written in C (surprise) and full with `static` variables. Even if the referencing / unreferencing is properly managed in the interpreter itself (I assume that), it still can be an issue in every individual wrapper library which is embedding non-python code.

Comment: It might be interesting, for debugging purposes, to add a custom deleter to your `shared_ptr<library::Library>` and print the `use_count()`. If you see a call to the custom deleter and a `use_count` that goes from 2 to 1, it may indicate that some circular dependency of objects was created somewhere behind the scene.
If the `shared_ptr` is never copied, it might be interesting to check the code with a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I doubt this is the **minimal reproducible sample**. The fact that you introduced destructors for your classes means you may actually implement some none-trivial logic inside them; your code essentially violates **rule 350**. Fix that problem and come back fo further discussion. Don't make any excuses in any form for breaking the rules: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Please copy the code *from the question* to empty file\[s] outside of your project, **change absolutely nothing**, build, and run. Do you get the same error you are asking about? If not, this is not a [mcve].

Comment: When I build the project from git, I do see messages you say are missing.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I'm sorry, I leaved in the sample on Git working, but useless version of Python code. I have reverted the line makes the problem. Try it one more time please.

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that [It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).